# NGINX display the same page all the time

Tags: node.js, linux, nginx

I am trying to work with a VPS Linux server, I installed node.js on it, and every time I try opening any other page on my website it displays the same index.html file.
For example, if I go to http://mywebsite.com/test.html
(while test.html is file located on my server, it displays index.html) This is happening with any html file.

Can someone help me understand how can I fix this?

Nginx default file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


root /home/webstud/myapp ;


    server_name MYWEBSITE.COM;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/myapp;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /css/ {
    }

    location /images/ {
    }
   location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/backend;
    }
```

Node.js default file:

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html' })
  // fs.createReadStream('index.html').pipe(res)
  fs.createReadStream('myapp/index.html').pipe(res)
})

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

Thank you.

Comment: your node.js server is delivering only `index.html` for every request. If you want to serve only static html, you can only use nginx for that, by setting the [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) and do not need a JS server on port 3000

Comment: how can I deliver any file?

Comment: do I need to add:
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html =404;
}
like that?

Comment: [usgin nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/) and [using only nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/)

Comment: not working :/ 
i tried the following:

Comment: const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')

// const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
 // res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html' })
  // fs.createReadStream('index.html').pipe(res)
  // fs.createReadStream('myapp/myapp.js').pipe(res)
// res.sendFile("pathTofile");
// })

http.createServer(function (req,res) {
 fs.readFile(__dirname + req.url, function (err,data) {
 if (err) {
 res.writeHead(404);
 res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
 return;
 }
 res.writeHead(200);
 res.end(data);
});
}).server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)